# No water is coming out after baking the fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I literally never got it right...
This time I'm trying to make a pool/fountain.
The water should be overflowed the cylinder and onto the cube.
But now nothing comes out after baking.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

no wonder: your smallest resolution unit (pink) is much bigger than your inflow(blue). The water will only flow if the resolution unit is smaller than your inflow and fits totally in it (better several times). So either increase your resolution a lot or increase the size of your inflow. And maybe watch some beginner mantaflow tutorials - there are thousands of free tutorials on yt.

And just a hint: if you don't want to collect more downvotes (as you did also in your former questions) you should invest more time in writing good question. You should at least insert some screenshots of your setup and of your relevant settings.

Comment: thanks for answering I'll check yt for basic tutorials. sorry for the questions I thought the files are enough..

Comment: @coffeeblood It's not only the contents of the question as Chris already pointed out... he still was able to answer to your problem - but the title could be more significant as well. "[something] doesn't work" leaves so many room for interpretation and gives no hint on what it is that "doesn't work".

Comment: An ideal post should be as close to self-explanatory as possible. So that it doesn't require people to go out of their way clicking external links out of BSE or spend time downloading files for nothing. But more importantly, each post you make on BSE or any forum is not just for you, it's for everyone. If anyone gets the same issue later, they should be able to find your post, with the solution beneath it. Downloading a file should only be a last resort when the issue just requires it or the poster is unable to provide more technical info: it should be the last thing done.

Comment: @L0Lock "it should be the last thing done" - well spoken, just my thoughts exactly. Unfortunately it is often the first thing to ask for in comments, even when a quick look most of the time is enough to see what the problem is.